# Why do serial ports send data least significant bit first?

Tags: serial-port

On Wikipedia, it says the following about [serial ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Data_bits):

> Most serial communications designs send the data bits within each byte
>   LSB (Least significant bit) first.

What is the reason why most serial communications transmit LSB first? Is there a historical reason for this? Arbitrary? Looking for a concrete reason.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the reason **why** is that the engineers that designed the first telex system a century ago thought that was best.  And, if you ever study the insides of one of those ancient machines that translate serial data into actual printed copy with no electronic, only mechanical, devices; you may realize what their thoughts may have been.

In the subsequent time, there have been some advantages to using this order with more advanced electronics, that never occurred to the pioneers.  Most notably that the existence of an extra bit can interact with the stop bit (in async) for some optimization of the logic in a UART.  But mostly, there was just hardly ever any real reason for being different.  If you do it in the same order as the installed base, you can talk to all those existing machines.  If you insist on being different your systems can only talk to each other.

Comment: What is the optimization you were talking about ?